# Copy Construction in Initializer Lists

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list, copy-elision

I was exploring the *ugly* world of [`std::intializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

As far as I've understood from the standard:

*§ 11.6.4*:

> 5. An object of type std::initializer_list is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation
>      generated and materialized (7.4) a prvalue of type “array of N const E”, where N is the number of elements
>      in the initializer list. **Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the
>      initializer list**, and the std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer to that array. [ Note: A
>      **constructor** or conversion function selected **for the copy** shall be accessible (Clause 14) in the context of
>      the initializer list. — end note ] [...]

So, in case the type `E` is a *class*, I expect the *copy constructor* to be called.

---

The following class does not allow copy construction:

```
struct NonCopyable {
  NonCopyable() = default;   
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

I am going to try to instantiate a `std::initializer_list` with this class.

```
#include <vector>

void foo() {
  std::vector<NonCopyable>{NonCopyable{}, NonCopyable{}};
}
```

With `g++-8.2 -std=c++14` I get what I expect, compiler error:

`error: use of deleted function 'NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&)'`.

Perfect!

---

However, the behaviour changes with the new standard.

Indeed, `g++-8.2 -std=c++17` compiles.

[Compiler Explorer Test](https://godbolt.org/z/_NILEz)

---

I thought it was because of the new requirement about [`copy elision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) provided by the new standard, at first.

However, changing the *standard library implementation* (keeping c++17) the error comes back:

`clang-7 -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++` fails:

`'NonCopyable' has been explicitly marked deleted here NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;`

[Compiler Explorer Test](https://godbolt.org/z/AWAX1E)

---

So what am I missing?

1) Does C++17 *require* copy-elision in the *copy construction* of elements of `initializer_list`?

2) Why `libc++` implementation does not compile here?

---

**Edit**
Please note that, in the example `g++ -std=c++17` (which compiles), if I change the *default constructor* as "user defined":

```
struct NonCopyable {
  NonCopyable();
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

the program does not compile anymore (not because of link error).

[Compiler Explorer Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7CySC)

Comment: "*changing the standard library implementation (keeping c++17)*" You're also changing *compilers*, so it's a lot less trivial than you're making it sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that this type:

```
struct NonCopyable {
  NonCopyable() = default;   
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

is *trivially copyable*. So as an optimization, since `std::initializer_list` is just backed by an array, what libstdc++ is doing is simply memcpying the the whole contents into the `vector` as an optimization. Note that this type is trivially copyable even though it has a deleted copy constructor!

This is why when you make the default constructor user-provided (by just writing `;` instead of `= default;`), is suddenly doesn't compile anymore. That makes the type no longer trivially copyable, and hence the memcpy path goes away.

As to whether or not this behavior is correct, I am not sure (I doubt there's a requirement that this code *must not* compile? I submitted [89164](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89164) just in case). You certainly *want* libstdc++ to take that path in the case of trivially copyable - but maybe it needs to exclude this case? In any case, you can accomplish the same by additionally deleting the copy assignment operator (which you probably want to do anyway) - that would also end up with the type not being trivially copyable.

This didn't compile in C++14 because you could not construct the `std::initializer_list` - copy-initialization there required the copy constructor. But in C++17 with guaranteed copy elision, the construction of `std::initializer_list` is fine. But the problem of actually constructing the `vector` is totally separate from `std::initializer_list` (indeed, this is a total red herring). Consider:

```
void foo(NonCopyable const* f, NonCopyable const* l) {
  std::vector<NonCopyable>(f, l);
}
```

That compiles in C++11 just fine... at least since gcc 4.9.

Comment: 1) Default ctor's user-providedness doesn't affect trivially copyable. However, libstdc++ is dispatching on trivial, not trivially copyable (which is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68350). 2) Deleting the copy assignment operator doesn't make the type non-trivially-copyable either, but libstdc++'s optimization is engaged via `std::copy`, and so it does not apply the optimization if the type is not copy-assignable.

Comment: Finally, this is technically library-level UB. Anything is conforming.

Comment: "*Note that this type is trivially copyable even though it has a deleted copy constructor!*" I'm pretty sure that this behavior is not legal in accord with the standard. Even if the copy constructor is never called (pursuant to the "as if" rule), `initializer_list` constructors for containers require that the `value_type` is CopyConstructible, which `NonCopyable` is not. Specifically, it requires [EmplaceConstructible from the value type of the range, which `NonCopyable` is not](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/container.requirements#sequence.reqmts-4).

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, and the penalty for breaking a *Requires* is undefined behavior, see [res.on.required]. So it's perfectly legal for the implementation to ignore it and do anything they want instead.

Comment: Ah, and I'll correct my 2): additionally deleting copy assignment does make it non-trivially-copyable in the current WP as a result of DR1734 (the move members are suppressed), but that DR doesn't appear to have been implemented in the current implementations.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I need to rewrite most of this... at least it's mostly in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

> Does C++17 require copy-elision in the copy construction of elements of initializer_list?

Initializing the elements of an `initializer_list` never guaranteed the use of "copy construction". It merely performs copy *initialization*. And whether copy initialization invokes a copy constructor or not depends entirely on what is going on in the initialization.

If you have a type that is convertible from `int`, and you do `Type i = 5;`, that is copy initialization. But it will not invoke the copy constructor; it will instead invoke the `Type(int)` constructor.

And yes, the construction of the elements of the array the `initializer_list` references are susceptible to copy elision. Including C++17's rules for guaranteed elision.

That being said, what *isn't* susceptible to those rules is the initialization of the `vector` *itself*. `vector` must copy the objects from an `initializer_list`, so they must have an accessible copy constructor. How a compiler/library implementation manages to get around this is not known, but it is definitely off-spec behavior.